# Реализация Boolean.hashCode()

Tags: java

Почему метод `Boolean.hashCode(boolean value)` возвращает значения 1231, если параметр равен `true`, и 1237, если параметр равен `false`? В чем смысл именно этих значений?

```
public static int hashCode(boolean value) {
    return value ? 1231 : 1237;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1231 и 1237 это просто произвольные простые числа (причем достаточно большие).

**Почему именно простые?**

Предположим, что для вычисления хэш-кода true мы используем не 1231 (простое число), а 1000 (составное число). Также и для значения false: вместо 1237 (простое число) взяли 2000 (составное число). Допустим у нас есть хэш-таблица, в которой количество bucket’ов равно N. Тогда bucket в который попадет наш объект Boolean вычислется по формуле: hashCode % N, т.е. Boolean(true) попадет в bucket 1000 % N, а Boolean(false) в bucket 2000 % N.

**Ну и что?**

Если мы внимательно посмотрим на остатки от деления, то обнаружим, что использование составных чисел влечет за собой множество коллизий. Например:

- Остаток от деления 1000 % 8 такой же как и у 2000 % 8
- Остаток от деления 1000 % 10 такой же как и у 2000 % 10
- Остаток от деления 1000 % 20 такой же как и у 2000 % 20

Таким образом, для вычисления хэш-кодов выбираются простые числа. При их использовании будет минимальное количество коллизий, в чилу того что у них нет общих делителей.

**Почему именно большие простые числа? Чем 2 и 3 не устраивают?**

При вычислении хеш-кодов для составных объектов обычно используют хеш-коды входящих в объект компонентов. При этом если, у нас получается маленькое по величине значение хэш-кода, то при большом количестве buсket’ов растет вероятность неравномерного распределения объектов по хэш-таблице.

По материалам:
[Boolean.hashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912303/boolean-hashcode)

PS. Спасибо [first-sin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/338621/first-sin) за наводку